# How to make Grid responsive using bootstrap in react js?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm using the bootstrap in my react js project. I'm using css grid to display some cards but it is not responsive.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Project.css";
export const Project = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container tracked">
          <div className="card">
          <div className="face">
            <div className="content">
              <h2 className="titler">TITLE</h2>
              <p>
                BLABLA</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="face">
            <h4>Product Search</h4>
          </div>
          </div>
       </div>
   );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```css
.tracked{
    width: 1200px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

There should be three cards in a row and that should be responsive. As of now it's not responsive but it's working good in the desktop.

Comment: Use reactstrap. Its bootstrap packagae for react. Then you can use its Row and Col.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/layout/grid-examples/) MDBootstrap

```
import { MDBContainer, MDBRow, MDBCol } from "mdbreact";

const gridExamplesPage = () => {
  return (
    <MDBContainer>
      <MDBRow>
        <MDBCol size="4">.col-4</MDBCol>
        <MDBCol size="4">.col-4</MDBCol>
        <MDBCol size="4">.col-4</MDBCol>
      </MDBRow>

      <MDBRow>
        <MDBCol sm="4">.col-sm-4</MDBCol>
        <MDBCol sm="4">.col-sm-4</MDBCol>
        <MDBCol sm="4">.col-sm-4</MDBCol>
      </MDBRow>

      <MDBRow>
        <MDBCol md="4">.col-md-4</MDBCol>
        <MDBCol md="4">.col-md-4</MDBCol>
        <MDBCol md="4">.col-md-4</MDBCol>
      </MDBRow>

      <MDBRow>
        <MDBCol lg="4">.col-lg-4</MDBCol>
        <MDBCol lg="4">.col-lg-4</MDBCol>
        <MDBCol lg="4">.col-lg-4</MDBCol>
      </MDBRow>

      <MDBRow>
        <MDBCol xl="4">.col-xl-4</MDBCol>
        <MDBCol xl="4">.col-xl-4</MDBCol>
        <MDBCol xl="4">.col-xl-4</MDBCol>
      </MDBRow>
    </MDBContainer>
  );
}

export default gridExamplesPage;`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it and let me know if it works for you. I have used grid system in Bootstrap. Check this link if you have any doubts (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/).

Thanks and regards,
Parthasarathi RV

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Project.css";
export const Project = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container-fluid text-center">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-4">
             <div className="card">
               <div className="face">
                <div className="content">
                  <h2 className="titler">TITLE</h2>
                  <p>BLABLA</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="face">
                <h4>Product Search</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-4">
             <div className="card">
               <div className="face">
                <div className="content">
                  <h2 className="titler">TITLE</h2>
                  <p>BLABLA</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="face">
                <h4>Product Search</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-4">
             <div className="card">
               <div className="face">
                <div className="content">
                  <h2 className="titler">TITLE</h2>
                  <p>BLABLA</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="face">
                <h4>Product Search</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
   );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

u need to import bootstrap css like this:
first install bootstrap:

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

or

```
yarn add bootstrap
```

and then import css to your project

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
```

and you can use react-bootstrap:

```
npm install react-bootstrap
```